# Is there an English word for "fargin"?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation, yiddish

I noted a Yiddish word that appears to have no English analogue:

"[*fargin*](http://ohr.edu/this_week/israel_forever/2660)" or "פארגין", which means something like "to not withhold a favor from someone [for no reason]" or "not to begrudge [something from someone]."
Can anyone think of an English word that could be used in place of "*fargin*"?

Comment: The downvoters probably think that finding one Yiddish word that doesn't have a counterpart in English 'prove[s] their point [that Yiddish is a much richer language than English]' in precisely the same way that Athletico Madrid's leading 1 - 0 after 92 minutes proves they are Champions of Europe. There are 1 000 000 + words in English, and countless polysemes. But Italian's arguably better for operas.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's fine but... I never said I agreed with them. Do you think I should edit the question to clarify? And yes, Italian is definitely better for opera.

Comment: 'and prove their point' _should_ be taken as your view here; it needs recasting.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth How about "and attempt to prove their point"?

Comment: Partly: that deals with what appears to be a rather fanciful claim by _you_. However, it is still certainly you making the unsupported claim 'Many people like to say that Yiddish is a much richer language'. How many? Where is the evidence that they do? As an aside, what's the Yiddish term for pseudopseudohypoparathyroidism? Midmark? Frustum? Abacinate? Abderian? Syzygy? Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious?

Comment: It's really difficult to *guess* at an English word which is the equivalent when you have given us so limited a definition.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's something that I hear pretty often, with different words....what kind of support should this claim have?

Comment: @medica better?

Comment: Yes, it is better. Using it in a sentence would also help.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth First, what kind of evidence do you want? The edit in your comment didn't make it any clearer. Second, what does the Yiddish term for Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious have to do with anything?

Comment: @AnotherUser - your claim to prove, not his to disprove.

Comment: 'I have heard at least 17 people say that Yiddish is a much richer language than English ...' would probably not be contested as a preamble. I probably wouldn't start a question with something like 'Perhaps two people I've spoken to over the last 15 years have mentioned the Yiddish language', but it's probably true.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth How's that?

Comment: How many, over what time period, and of what ethnicity? It still sounds like a point-scoring exercise. The actual question is valid, but you might as well set the context with something like 'We all know that the Eskimos have as many as 1000 different words for reindeer. People bigging up Yiddish tend not to mention this.'

Comment: @AnotherUser: You can use "translation" tag for these kind of questions. Also it is better to use objective language here. You could just say "it is mentioned as untranslatable", instead of mentioning some opinions that compare languages. Other than that, you did not have to delete the first meaning you mentioned, you can just clarify with additions.

Comment: I'm not a downvoter but this question seems to be to be about Yiddish not English.

Comment: @TheMathemagician How is this a question about Yiddish? I'm asking for an English word!

Comment: I think a few examples would help.  I don't see how anyone could vote without proficiency in Yiddish without some good examples.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks for the helpful edit!

Comment: @aNOTHERuSER - Fargin ?

Comment: @stevenking Touche ;)

Comment: "*Fargin* means something like "to not withhold a favor from someone [for no reason]" is **not** it. Please check again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no single-word equivalent for *fargin* in English, though there are single-word antonyms like *begrudge* and *resent*. In the same way, there is no single-word equivalent in English of the French word *frileux* (someone who has the tendency to feel cold).

That doesn't make Yiddish or French "richer" than English; there are many words in the English language that have no single-word equivalent in either French or Yiddish. Every language has holes in it, where it takes several words to express a single concept. Sometimes languages will "borrow" (without ever really meaning to return) words from other languages when they're especially useful for plastering over those holes. *Fargin* doesn't cover a very big hole in English since we already have ways of expressing a good deal of nuance around the concept, ranging from merely not resenting through congratulating and on to sharing in the joy. In a sense, you could say that English is richer and more nuanced precisely because it lacks a single word to cover all of the spectrum of attitude that Yiddish packs into the word *fargin*. *Schmooze*, on the other hand, was worth <s>stealing</s> borrowing.

Comment: Never said which language I considered to be "richer" ...but thanks for the great answer!

Comment: "In a sense, you could say that English is richer and more nuanced precisely because it lacks a single word to cover all of the spectrum of attitude that Yiddish packs into the word fargin." Great thought there!

Comment: So you were just looking for confirmation that there is no equivalent? In my answer, I was just trying to find the closest ones. Also, words might gain this sense in the context. For example, different senses of "volunteer" might have different words in Yiddish. In the end, we were trying to find the closest ones instead of saying there is no equivalent.

Comment: @ermanen No, I wasn't....and thanks (again) for your high quality answer!

Comment: @ermanen And I never would have seen your comment, had I not been called back to this page by another user....if you want your comments to be seen by a specific person, put them under that person's post, or ping them with an "@" sign like I just did ;)

Answer (score 2):

**[Milce-witter](http://useful_english.enacademic.com/719076/milce)** - "knowing mercy."

**[Milce](http://useful_english.enacademic.com/719076/milce)** Mercy, clemency, forbearance, favour. Often coupled with ore, grace, or mercy. Also pl. mercies.

Answer (score 1):

How do you like *grant*?

> [grant](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/grant): to permit as a favor, indulgence, etc.

Alternately, consider *permit*.

> **permit**: to allow to be granted

Comment: It's OK....but the idea of "fargin" is a little more complex...it's more like "not withholding a favor" more than just granting a favor...

Comment: Would Merriam-Webster's 4th definition of "suffer" be what your are looking for?      http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suffer                                  1  a :  to submit to or be forced to endure <suffer martyrdom>
b :  to feel keenly :  labor under <suffer thirst>
2
:  undergo, experience
3
:  to put up with especially as inevitable or unavoidable
4
:  to allow especially by reason of indifference <the eagle suffers little birds to sing — Shakespeare>

Answer (score 1):

As a verb, I'm going to say ***[bestow](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bestow)***. It has the connotation of giving willingly.

> To present as a gift or an honor; confer

---

A word that is as close as possible would be ***[ungrudging](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ungrudging)***

> not begrudging; not reluctant or resentful; wholehearted.

So, you can also say *support/give ungrudgingly*.

---

***[volunteer](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/volunteer)*** might fit also.

> (tr) to perform, give, or communicate voluntarily: *to volunteer help; to volunteer a speech.*

Comment: "Give ungrudgingly" is very good, +1 (though my spellcheck doesn't recognize it!;)....but I'm looking more for a single word, if one indeed exists

Comment: I think _volunteer_ and _bestow_ are the closest words as a single word.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, *vouchsafe* comes closest; "grant"/"concede"/"spare"/"allow" are more approximate, though in wider use outside of Shakespeare.

> **vouchsafe** (third-person singular simple present vouchsafes, present
>   participle vouchsafing, simple past and past participle vouchsafed)
>
> To graciously give, to condescendingly grant a right, benefit,
>   outcome, etc.; to deign to acknowledge.  [quotations ▼] To receive or
>   accept in condescension.

The difference with "fargin" is that it is quite common and natural in Yiddish.

Comment: Right. "Fargin" doesn't have the connotation of condescension.