# Translation for Dutch word 'gunnen'

Tags: single-word-requests

In Dutch we can say 'ik gun jou de opdracht', meaning 'I ... you the assignment'. It's mixture of *allow to have* and *don't begrudge* I guess. If I translate the dictionary, it would be '*to desire or approve that somebody else has or gets something*'.

A related word would be 'gunfactor', used in business and making deals. It almost sounds like giving an contract to a party you approve of, but that's not quite it. In this case one approves, desires and doesn't begrudge.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but [this post](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/266611/whats-a-word-for-a-positive-kind-of-envy-without-the-sense-of-resentment) may provide you with helpful information

Comment: *Award*, perhaps? At least, that's what Google Translate says.

Comment: There is no English equivalent: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172967/is-there-an-english-word-for-fargin

Comment: Whenever I have to translate that, I usually say *I think he/she deserves it more.*

Comment: I ***want you to have*** the assignment.

Comment: This word is just as hard to translate as 'gedogen'. It just doesn't work in other languages than Dutch.

Comment: What about "cede?"

Comment: @RandomStranger I like that actually. I'll keep that in mind together with _to not begrudge_. That should cover a lot of the cases.

Comment: @Glorfindel It works pretty well in German - "gönnen".

Answer (score 1):

While not an exact substitute, the term *[favor](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/favor)* has some connection

> Feel or show approval or preference for

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Similarly, *[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/favor)*

> to be for; support; advocate; endorse

Answer (score 1):

The basic meaning of the word is *to not begrudge*, which is in fact what Englishmen often use when they want to express this exact sense. I do not believe this can be said in one word in English.

A secondary meaning is *to grant* [a government contract, etc.], which can be translated as *grant, award*, or similar.

Answer (score 1):

"Gun een ander ook eens wat!"
"Het is 'm gegund"

Anyone?

My approximations: "Invoke some altruism!" resp. "I hope he gets a break with that". To me 'gunnen' means feeling content/happy about the case of - or the possibility for - someone else to have/achieve something I would have liked myself, or is generally likeable.

Comment: The question already has an explanation of what the word means, and asks for a (single-word) translation.

Comment: As someone that doesn't speak Dutch this answer makes no sense to me

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the Dutch *gunnen* to express that you want someone to get something, for example, you want them to get the job the applied for. In English you might use the idiom [*to root for someone or something*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/root+for):

> I'm rooting for you to get the position you applied for.

The Dutch equivalent would be:

> Ik gun je de positie waarvoor je gesolliciteerd hebt.

Comment: Well, not quite the same in my opinion. Rooting is active, *gunnen* is more passive.

Comment: To root for is not active per se, from the link: "to wish the best for someone or something in an endeavor or activity."